# Save varying size double array in MySQL database using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to store the coefficients of a rational function into a `MySQL 5.5` database. This is done using `PHP 5`, which I am rather new to.

In more detail I have two arrays each representing the coefficients of the numerator and denominator polynomial (factored form). The size of both arrays is dynamic between 1 and 10 and if needed I can sort the numbers into any arbitrary order. All numbers are of type double.

Stored in the Database I only have to compare the functions for equality. Which means I only need to figure out if both arrays have the same coefficients (order does not matter). E.g. [1,2,3] and [3,1,2] are the same.

As MySQL does not offer to save arrays directly, I am not sure how to approach this task in the best way.

My current idea, I am yet unsure if feasible, is to sort both arrays in descending order. Then typecast each double to a string of 8 symbols, concatenating all strings. Afterwards I would store that (long) string as `VARCHAR`. To compare two functions I would compare the numerator and denominator string and if both match, the functions are the same.

A problem I see with that approach is the 'typecasting'. Interpreting a double as 8 characters is pretty crude and I have no idea if the resulting symbols might end the string early or cause any trouble.

Which brings my to my question, does this way work or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You can sort the arrays to a consistent order and then use SERIALIZE to convert the arrays to a string. Normally this is to be avoided in MySQL (as someone inevitably wants to search for a value within that serialized array from MySQL) but as you just want to treat it as a single value it might be OK.

Comment: If I serialize the array, I might run into a problem when the numbers are long. Take for example the number 'e' which approximately is '2.718281828459046...' which would instantly cost 17 Byte just to store a single number (instead of a 4 byte float / 8 byte double). Interpreting / typecasting would get rid of that issue and is kind of a serialization.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the space. If necessary you could store it in a TEXT type field, and if you are worried about the performance of that you can store a hash of the full serialised array. Hence you only need to check the text value when you have eliminated almost all possible matches. Trouble with interpretting and type casting is you lose the precise value of the fields (in which case you may as well just store the hash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should work, and is probably a good way to do it.

If you're only checking for equality, you just need to convert to some canonical string representation, and save that in the database.  A shorter representation is better for space usage, but making it still human-readable would be nice as well, since that should help with ad-hoc queries and debugging.

Note that order probably *does* matter for a [rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function). Also, if you're dealing with [floating-point](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), you need to watch out for numbers that aren't exactly equal but might be close enough for what you're doing.

A few options:

- Store two columns, each a comma-delimited list of numbers (with zeroes for missing coefficients in the middle). Put them together with [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).
- Store one column, containing two comma-delimited lists separates by a `/` character.
- Store two `VARBINARY` columns, each 8 × *n* bytes long (where *n* is the number of coefficients). This would be easy in C or Java or perl, in PHP use the [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function.
- Store one `VARBINARY` column, format *length byte* + *data* + *data*. Once again, user the `pack` function.

Comment: You are right, I should have been more clear about the coefficients. The polynomial is given as a product of factors (which are all linear in my case). So [1,2,3] would relate to (x+1)*(x+2)*(x+3), hence [1,2,3] and [3,2,1] would result in the same polynomial.